# Why is the acronym element obsolete in HTML5?

Tags: html

An acronym is something like NASA which can be spelled out as National Aeronautics and Space Administration.

An abbreviation is something like id which is short for identification.

To me the two are not the same so why is the acronym element obsolete in HTML5 in favour of the abbr element?

Comment: Is this question on topic for Stack Overflow? I doubt there is a definitive answer (unless some W3C employee happens to come along). Anyway, while not every abbreviation is an acronym, [every acronym is an abbreviation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acronym). So it's making life easier for us by not having to remember to use what tag for which.

Comment: I don't see why this isn't on topic, similar questions have been asked in the past and people have answered them. I didn't realise that an acronym is an abbreviation so if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as it does in fact answer the question.

Comment: That's fair – but I don't think I am *answering* your question. Only aforementioned (hypothetical) W3C employee can; I can only hazard an educated guess. If, say, you asked about `<dir>`, I would not have a clue. Or why `<big>` had to go but `<small>` is allowed to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Obsolete elements](https://html-differences.whatwg.org/#obsolete-elements) section of the HTML5  [Differences from HTML4](https://html-differences.whatwg.org/) doc, which says:

> `acronym` is not included because it has created a lot of confusion. Web developers are to use `abbr` for abbreviations.